# How to add column in dask dataframe that reflecs whether date value (from column) is member of holidays

Tags: python, pandas, dask, python-datetime

I have a large data set of time series data (350 million rows,15GB) with date-times (half hourly resolution).

I am therefore using dask to handle and parallelize as much as possible.

I'm stuck in what should be a trivial task. I have a list of dates that are holidays, created using the holidays package:

```
NSWholidays = holidays.Australia(years= [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014], state='NSW')
```

And I have a 'date' column in my dask dataframe.

I want to add a new column called `'IsWorkDay'` where 1 will reflect days which are not holidays and are from Monday to Friday, and 0 will reflect weekends or holidays.

I've tried dozens of combinations trying to find the required syntax for dask's requirements to paralellise this but the only solution I've managed to get working is using .apply which is frustratingly slow for the task (multiple hours). In short, the line below works but is too slow:

```
SGSCData['IsWorkDay'] = SGSCData.apply(lambda row: int(row.weekday<6 and not row.Date in NSWholidays), axis=1, meta=(None, 'int64'))
```

How can I make this faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you would use in pure pandas? Have you tried with map_partitions?

Comment: I could never get the map_partitions syntax to work with my example and dask nicely. Can you show me how it should be written?

Comment: Do you mind to add you `SGSCData.head().to_dict()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'm not quite sure about your logic for weekends. Anyway this is what I'm able to do without use `apply` or `map_partitions`. My `dask.__version__` is `1.1.1`. As you can see using exactly the same vectorial solution you would use in `pandas` your computation takes less than `15s` on an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz`

```py
import pandas as pd
import holidays
import dask.dataframe as dd
NSWholidays = holidays.Australia(years=list(range(2010,2021)), state='NSW')
# this is slightly more than 31.5M rows
dates = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', end='2020-01-01', freq="10S")
ddf = pd.DataFrame({"Date":dates})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(ddf, npartitions=10)

ddf["IsWorkDay"] = (~((ddf["Date"].dt.weekday>=5) | 
                      (ddf["Date"].dt.date.isin(NSWholidays)))).astype(int)

%%time
ddf = ddf.compute()

CPU times: user 1.07 s, sys: 1.48 s, total: 2.55 s
Wall time: 13.9 s
```

Comment: brilliant! Thanks